# Where can i find a good example of archiving objects for persistence for the iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I have an object that contains about half a dozen properties. I expect to save maybe a dozen or more of these objects to my documents folder. My solution is to save the data using NSEncoding and NSKeyed/Archiver/Unarchiver. Anyone have a better strategy or approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver will work fine. If each file only has a half dozen properties, you might consider whether putting the entire object list in one file would be simpler for you to load/save/keep consistent.